# what is the best solution for GNU gettext installation in windows?

Tags: python, django, gettext

in **windows** for a django project on pycharm, my Django and dependencies are installed on **venv**.
I wanted to modify one **.po** file and test it if it's working or not, it seems that this change needs to commit by this command: `*django-admin makemessages -l -ja*` I tried it and I faced with this error:
"*CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.*"
I tried to install gettext for my project but it didn't work. pip install python-gettext didn't work as well.
and some of the answers for similar issue were not clear
I want to know the best solution for this situation ...

Comment: Hi, please add more details about your environment and details on what do you mean by "it didn't work"(like, error messages, steps you were taking to install these packages, etc.)

Comment: Hi, I mean that I got errors by "didn't work", about the errors I got same errors in Django when run makemessages command : "CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed." about the steps of installation, there was a file in https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html I installed it and it was supposed to set the path by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install gettext for Windows: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

It is not a Python package.

Comment: yes I did this but I don't know how to install it, is it enough to install and run it? which version (shared or static)

Comment: I'm not a Windows user but, yes, running the installer should be enough. And in doubt take the static version.

Comment: I installed and run it as you say and it works for me, thank you!